# SQL Remove last comma from Concatenated Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to concatenate columns that I'm separating by adding a comma. I'd like to remove the last comma and the only way I can think to do this is using the convoluted way below:

```
SELECT        
id,

CASE WHEN LEN(
            ISNULL(CASE WHEN intExtraTime > 0 THEN Convert(varchar(3),intExtraTime) + '% Extra Time, ' END,'') + 
            ISNULL(CASE WHEN intprocessor = 1 THEN 'Laptop, ' END,'') +
            ISNULL(CASE WHEN intRest = 1 THEN 'Rest Break, ' END,'') + 
            ISNULL(CASE WHEN intReader = 1 THEN 'Reader, ' END,'') +
            ISNULL(CASE WHEN intScribe = 1 THEN 'Scribe, ' END,''))>0 
THEN 
    SUBSTRING(
                ISNULL(CASE WHEN intExtraTime > 0 THEN Convert(varchar(3),intExtraTime) + '% Extra Time, ' END,'') + 
                ISNULL(CASE WHEN intprocessor = 1 THEN 'Laptop, ' END,'') +
                ISNULL(CASE WHEN intRest = 1 THEN 'Rest Break, ' END,'') + 
                ISNULL(CASE WHEN intReader = 1 THEN 'Reader, ' END,'') +
                ISNULL(CASE WHEN intScribe = 1 THEN 'Scribe, ' END,''),1,
            LEN(
                ISNULL(CASE WHEN intExtraTime > 0 THEN Convert(varchar(3),intExtraTime) + '% Extra Time, ' END,'') + 
                ISNULL(CASE WHEN intprocessor = 1 THEN 'Laptop, ' END,'') +
                ISNULL(CASE WHEN intRest = 1 THEN 'Rest Break, ' END,'') + 
                ISNULL(CASE WHEN intReader = 1 THEN 'Reader, ' END,'') +
                ISNULL(CASE WHEN intScribe = 1 THEN 'Scribe, ' END,''))-1)
END

FROM            dbo.Candidate AS ExamOptions
```

Anyone know a better more cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Code isn't product specific. The first set of isnull statements are what I want to concatenate. I've wrapped this in a outer case to deal with the comma at the end.

Comment: ISNULL is product specific. Convert is product specific. LEN too, and + for string concatenation.

Comment: And that SUBSTRING is also product specific.

Comment: Sorry @jarlh I thought you meant the package that the database is written for. Have updated the tags. SQL Server

Comment: Great. With the correct set of tags your query gets better attention, and better answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using SQL Server, based on the syntax.

I wouldn't do this by removing the *last* comma.  I would do this by removing the *first* comma using `stuff()`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN intExtraTime > 0 or intprocessor = 1 or intRest = 1 or
                 intReader = 1 or intScribe = 1
             THEN STUFF(COALESCE(CASE WHEN intExtraTime > 0 THEN ', ' + Convert(varchar(3), intExtraTime) + '% Extra Time' END,  '')
                        COALESCE(CASE WHEN intprocessor = 1 THEN ', Laptop' END, '') +
                        COALESCE(CASE WHEN intRest = 1 THEN ', Rest Break' END, '') + 
                        COALESCE(CASE WHEN intReader = 1 THEN ', Reader' END, '') +
                        COALESCE(CASE WHEN intScribe = 1 THEN ', Scribe' END, ''),
                        1, 2, '')
       END)
FROM dbo.Candidate ExamOptions;
```